# How do you get each element of list/tuple, where list is passed as parameter to function in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is the code snippet, which is unable to print items of the tuple. [Using python versions 2.6.8/2.7.10]

```
def lists (var, *st):
    print type(st)
    for item in range(1,len(st)):
        print "Items is:" + item
st = ['udf','var_udf']
lists("a",st)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does the Star operator mean in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921847/what-does-the-star-operator-mean-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

This would not be printing anything because you have used `item in range(1,len(st))` giving item the value of an integer. Instead do something like:

```
for item in st:
```

CODE:

```
def lists (var, *st):
    print type(st)
    for item in st:
        print "Items is:"
        print ' '.join(item)
st = ['','udf/','var_udf']
lists("a",st)
```

Comment: Thanks vaibhav. But, my actual requirement is to get the file-names using the itmes in that tuple. like create_udf.sql/create_var_udf.sql

For this,
def lists (var, *st):
    print type(st)
    for item in st:
        sql = "create_".join(item) + ".sql"
        print sql
st = ['udf','var_udf']
lists("a",st)

Giving output as:
<type 'tuple'>
udfcreate_var_udf.sql

Can you please help on this to achieve two sql file names

Comment: Then make sure the first element of st is always `''`and append `'/'` to all elements other than the last element.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] #list
print (a)

def b(list):
    for i in list:
        print (i) #each element of the list printed here

b(a) #calling def
```

If you are passing a list as an argument to the function, the below function will print each element of the list. If you want to perform any operations like append etc., you can add the code after `for` loop.

Comment: Try using `print ' '.join(i)` to make it cleaner

Comment: The question is "how to get each element of list or tuple where the list is passed as a parameter to a function in python?"